# passing parameters to a stored procedure from a temp table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a senario where i have to pass parameters to a stored procedure from a temptable

```
#student(table)
StudentID  Class
10008        A
10009        A
10010        C
```

The sproc accepts 2 parameters StudentID and Class.

```
Student_Fail @StudentID,@Class
```

I would like to execute this stored procedure for all the studentID(3 times).

How can this be done? using while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ideally you should re-write the stored procedure so that it can just use the #temp table directly, or create a different stored procedure, or just replicate in this code what the stored procedure tries to do for a single row. (Set-based operations are almost always better than processing one row at a time.)

Short of that, you'd have to use a cursor or while loop ([and no they aren't really different](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/26/bad-habits-to-kick-thinking-a-while-loop-isnt-a-cursor)).

```
DECLARE @StudentID INT, @Class CHAR(1);

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
  FOR SELECT StudentID, Class FROM #student;

OPEN c;

FETCH c INTO @StudentID, @Class;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.Student_Fail @StudentID, Class;
    FETCH c INTO @StudentID, @Class;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've indicated, a while loop will do:

```
declare @StudentID int
declare @Class char(1)

while exists (select 1 from #student)
begin

  select top 1 @StudentID = StudentID
    , @Class = Class
  from #student

  exec Student_Fail @StudentID, @Class

  delete from #student where @StudentID = StudentID

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this could be implemented as a `WHILE` loop, or as a `CURSOR`, since in this case they will do essentially the same thing, a row-by-row operation.

However, the ideal solution would be to re-implement the `Student_Fail` fail stored procedure to make it set-based instead of procedural.

For example, you can change your stored procedure to accept a [**table-valued parameter**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).

First, create the table type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.StudentClassTableType AS TABLE
( StudentID int, Class varchar(50) )
```

Next, alter the stored procedure (or create a new stored procedure) to accept the table type:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_FailStudents
(@tvpStudentsToFail dbo.StudentClassTableType READONLY)
-- Perform set-based logic using your table parameter.
UPDATE sc
SET Fail = 1
FROM dbo.StudentClass sc
JOIN @tvpStudentsToFail fail 
  ON fail.StudentID = sc.StudentID 
  AND fail.Class = sc.Class
```